# Accesing Ghost AWS Ubuntu Server in production

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-server, ghost-blog

I'm trying to **access my Ghost Blog** on AWS Ubuntu Server via http://x.x.x.x:2368, but all i get is site can't be reached.

Here are the steps i made:
- git cloned myBlog
- cd myBlog , npm install --production
 - npm start or npm start --production **console says site is running OK**

**Config file**

```
var path = require('path'),
    config;

config = {
    production: {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2368',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },

        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2368'
        }
    },
    development: {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2368',
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-dev.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: '2368'
        },
        paths: {
            contentPath: path.join(__dirname, '/content/')
        }
    },
}
```

**If i try to acces it from my pc via http://x.x.x.x:2368 i get the site can't be reached**
- The port 2368 is open on AWS, i also did `sudo ufw disable`

[image]

---

Testing AWS ports with a simple node app:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 2368;
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello world!\n');
}).listen(port);

console.log('listening on port', port);
```

**Result = works**

[image]

This means it must be something wrong with the config file from Ghost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following setting in config file

```
url : <external IP>:<port>
server : 0.0.0.0
port : port
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with AWS settings. I will advise you to ssh to the machine and try wget http://localhost:2368 and you will know if site is running or not .

Comment: I tried your advice and i get `OK status 200`. Here is a print https://s28.postimg.org/xu26d3bb1/2016_12_28_16h19_05.png

Comment: sounds weird.. Did you check why u getting "Segmentation fault" in your second screen ! Also, double check the ip address you are trying externally..Are you doing SSH also on same IP address ?

Comment: I don't know how to debug for `Segmentation fault`, but I tried `vim index.html` after doing your `wget` and it's totally empty. It supposed to be empty?

Comment: I updated the question with 1 small test i did to check if the port is open, and it is. Tried to ask this issue on Github also, but didn't get any help https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/7800

Comment: try going to /tmp directory and then do wget

Comment: Doing that from the `/tmp` folder eliminates the `segmentation faul error`, and i can see the whole index.html file correctly now ( https://s30.postimg.org/ecivlm3s1/2016_12_29_14h11_39.png ) !! But still trying to access the ip and port http://54.171.95.112:2368/ shows nothing. The site is running, but is not being shown outside :}

Comment: cool.. so we solved segmentation problem.. Most probably your user do not have write permissions in that directory. .. Not sure of your issue; I will have to really access your AWS account to debug the issue.

Comment: I managed to make it work with the above answer. I'm cool for now :)